# Does precision or recall have more importance? Are they to be considered equivalent measures of accuracy?

Tags: precision-recall

Does precision or recall have more importance? Or are they to be considered equivalent measures of accuracy?

They can produce different numbers; they refer to slightly different errors. But is it possible to say whether precision or recall would have more meaning as a measure of accuracy?

Comment: Depends entirely on the objective, what is more important if anything.

Comment: Do reinstate the quotation marks if you can show what you're quoting.

Answer (score 5):

Precision and recall are neither equivalent, nor measures of overall accuracy.

Let $TP, TN, FP, FN$ denote the number of true positives, true negatives, false positives, and false negatives. Accuracy, precision, and recall are defined as:

- **Accuracy** = $\frac{TP + TN}{TP + TN + FP + FN}$: The fraction of all cases that have been classified correctly.
- **Precision** = $\frac{TP}{TP + FP}$: The faction of cases classified as positive that are actually positive. This is equivalent to accuracy *on the subset of cases that have been classified as positive*. It can be interpreted as measuring how informative a 'positive' answer from the classifier is about the true class.
- **Recall** = $\frac{TP}{TP + FN}$: The fraction of positive cases that have been classified as positive. This is equivalent to accuracy *on the subset of cases that are actually positive*. It can be interpreted as measuring how completely the classifier identifies positive cases.

Each of these is a different way (among many other alternatives) of measuring the performance of a classifier. None can be said to be more or less meaningful than another; rather, they mean different things. Which performance measure(s) to use depends on the problem and goals. A classifier is used to guide decisions, and each action has different consequences in different circumstances. The performance measure should reflect how we care about these consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Recall and Precision can be useful measures if you interpret them correctly, but they can also be misleading. Consider as a simple example a series of $300$ "coin flips". The $i^{th}$ coin flip is heads (positive) with probability 
$$p_i = \frac{1}{1+\exp(-x_i)}$$
where $x_i$ is an observable feature. A model based on *logistic regression* might predict that a coin will be heads if $x_i > 0$. The success of this model depends on the distribution of the $x_i$. Here I will simulate them from a $N(0, 0.1)$ distribution, so that the model does only slightly better than average.

Let's compare this to a model which **always predicts heads** (called the null model).

Here are the results from a single simulation:

#### Logistic Regression Model:

- Accuracy: $0.53$
- Precision: $0.49$
- Recall: $0.53$
- $F_1$ Measure: $0.51$

#### Null Classifier (always one)

- Accuracy: $0.50$
- Precision: $0.50$
- Recall: $1.0$
- $F_1$ Measure: $0.67$

Note that for the null model, Recall will **always** be $1.0$ which makes sense by the definition. In fact all metrics except for Accuracy choose the null model here.

Let's look at the difference in each measure over $10,000$ simulations.

[image]

Note that Accuracy and precision choose the logistic regression based model the majority of the time, but Recall and $F_1$ measure choose the null model every single time.

So as others have said, which measure has more meaning truly depends on the problem. In my opinion, I would want to use the model which incorporates the features! But if false negatives are a really big deal, Recall suggests that the "smart model" is too costly.